# Grouping by and get details of every group in data frame

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I have a table like this :

```
   user   week  message  col2
   ----  -----  ----     ----
     A     1     Hi       30
     A     1     Hello    30
     A     2     To       30
     A     2     From     40
     B     1     call     30
     B     1     should   20
     B     2     sadas    50
```

I need to first group by user and then group by week and process some data.

ex :

```
    for user in everyUser:
        for week in everyWeek:
             week_data = list of all messages of the week.
```

Need to do something like this in Pandas, after loading it into data frame I  grouped the data by user and week and I don't know how to access the data after grouping.

And also how do we access the data by a user once we group it ?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `groupby.apply` pattern; In general, `apply` accepts a function and take data from each group of the grouped data frame as argument; In this case, if you just care about `message`, use `[]` to extract the column, and apply the `list` function to the message for each user which will give a list of messages for the user at corresponding week:

```
df.groupby(['user', 'week'])['message'].apply(list)

#user  week
#A     1          [Hi, Hello]
#      2           [To, From]
#B     1       [call, should]
#      2              [sadas]
#Name: message, dtype: object
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Waiting to finish 5 mins so that I can mark it correct.

Comment: Any idea regarding how to do group.get_group['col_name'] and get value as list ?

Answer (score 2):

```
#create your group
group = df.groupby(by=['user','week'])

#print all the groups and values
for k,v in group:
    print(k)
    print(v)
#get a group by the group key (user,week)    
group.get_group(('A', 1))   
Out[134]: 
  user  week message  col2
0    A     1      Hi    30
1    A     1   Hello    30
```

Comment: Is there a way to pick up just a single column as list after group.get_group ?

Comment: group.get_group(('A', 1)).message.tolist()

Comment: Wow, awesome. Wasted more than an hour to figure this out. Thank you